Bash do...done loop ignores last line in CSV file
I'm using Bash to iterate through a comma-delimited CSV file. There are no trailing blank spaces in each CSV line; however there is a carriage return after lines 1 (header), 2 (...ghi) and 3 (...789).
Issue to solve: The do..done is skipping the last line in the CSV.
Test1.csv file -->
lineNo,column1,column2,column3
1,abc,def,ghi
2,123,456,789
3,test1,test2,test3

Test1 Bash script:
setupFileLocation=test1.csv

while IFS=, read -r lineNo column1 column2 column3
do
    echo $lineNo

# skip the header line
done < <(tail -n +2 $setupFileLocation)

Desired result:
1
2
3

Actual result:
1
2

My short-term fix is to add a 4th line only containing a zero.
Test2.csv file -->
lineNo,column1,column2,column3
1,abc,def,ghi
2,123,456,789
3,test1,test2,test3
0

Test2 Bash script:
setupFileLocation=test2.csv

while IFS=, read -r lineNo column1 column2 column3
do
    echo $lineNo

# skip the header line
done < <(tail -n +2 $setupFileLocation)

Test2.csv results in:
1
2
3

If I eliminate any complexity caused by the "tail -n +2" in test 1 ...
setupFileLocation=test1.csv

while IFS=, read -r lineNo column1 column2 column3
do
    echo $lineNo

done < $setupFileLocation

... then I get:
lineNo
1
2

Related posts that do not give answer using while IFS... and do..done:

Iterating through a csv file
how to iterate through consecutive lines of a csv file
why is this simple FOR LOOP in my Linux bash not working?


I'll bet the file doesn't have a newline at the end. Fix that.

I gave you a link to a question that answers how to fix the loop. But be aware that many Unix text utilities expect all lines to end with newline. The POSIX specification says that this is required for valid text files. So it's best to fix the file rather than the script (although there's no reason not to do both for robustness).

Also see the My text files are broken! They lack their final newlines! section of BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?).
